# ¿Existe una acepción positiva de "vicio"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, significado, españa

Recuerdo cuando era joven y frecuentaba los salones recreativos, que observaba embobado cómo algunos se pasaban fase tras fase en algunas máquinas, y decíamos que "le tenía el vicio cogido" o que "tenía mucho vicio" o que era "un viciado".

Para mí el significado de aquella expresión, "tener vicio en algo", era el de "tener mucha habilidad" o "tener maestría" jugando a algo. Por ejemplo, podía ver a alguien dando patadas a un balón sin que se le cayera al suelo y exclamar: "¡Qué vicio!"

Hoy he ido a curiosear si ese significado de la palabra podía encontrarse en el DLE, pero [no lo he visto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=blIwWdu). Así que me preguntaba: ¿es este uso de la palabra común fuera de Andalucía o de España? ¿O tal vez yo le daba a la palabra un significado diferente al que le podían dar los demás?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No estas solo, querido Charlie, yo (madrileño) lo he usado igual. El ejemplo más claro que puedo pensar es la expresión

> Se te da de vicio

que entiendo que significa "Esto se te da muy bien debido al mucho tiempo que has dedicado a esta actividad, que es un *vicio* (en lugar de dedicarte a algo bueno o productivo)". Y creo que de ahí evolucionó a "has cogido maestría en esta cosa".

Es decir, aplicaría la sexta acepción del DRAE

> 6 . m. Gusto especial o demasiado apetito de algo, que incita a usarlo frecuentemente y con exceso.

Y con ese uso frecuente, vendría la maestría. Esta acepción parece estar libre de la connotación de "efecto dañino" de la palabra "vicio", aunque quizá esa adicción o "demasiado apetito" por la actividad es lo que se lo aporta.

En conclusión, creo que podrías decir que "se te da de vicio" tanto los juegos de ordenador como la programación, ambos debido a la extensa cantidad de horas que has dedicado a ambos. El primero es un hobby. El segundo, es un hobby y el instrumento de tu profesión. No podrías catalogarlo de "placer culpable" como el primero (aunque estoy seguro de que alguna vez tu mujer te ha dado una colleja por descuidar algo que tenías que hacer por estar *picando código* en algún proyecto personal...), pero en definitiva ha sido esa "adicción" (o vicio) la que te ha llevado a pasar muchas horas haciendo algo y adquirir maestría en ello.

Comment: Buen apunte. Digamos que las acepciones tienen todas connotaciones negativas y son algunas de estas locuciones las que han adquirido, si acaso, ese aspecto positivo.

Comment: De todas maneras, aunque la expresión (frase hecha) conlleve un aspecto positivo, la palabra vicio continúa sin tenerlo en si misma.

Answer (score 5):

Como complemento a la respuesta de Diego, la expresión "estar de vicio" también implica que algo es muy bueno (tan bueno que uno podría caer en el vicio de consumirlo continuamente).